# How to search text in files of all types (including binary)?

Tags: mac, search

I want to find some text inside binary files. Is it possible to do in Finder (it skips binary even if I set up "All kinds" of file types)? Otherwise I would be thankful for utility that can do it.

PS: I need to search among many files in directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging on Google I found [EasyFind.app](http://download.cnet.com/EasyFind/3000-2248_4-8707.html_hgPdea2b2uuNlxJLbA). This app can search in selected or all file types.

Comment: it doesn't search within binaries. Just try to search for SSLSetIoFuncs within all files, it will not find /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Comment: it's super weird that this has to be an app when os x is kind of unix and unix used to do this.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `strings` application in the Terminal.

```
strings filename(s) | grep text_to_search_for
```

From Wikipedia:

> In computer software, **strings** is a program in Unix-like operating systems that finds and prints text strings embedded in binary files such as executables.

I'm not aware of any way to use Finder to search for text in binary files.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this `strings` doesn't work well for `.docx` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Insider](http://www.tagtaxa.com/apps/insider/) for Mac.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you expand on this answer? What does this app do and why do you like it? Please take a look at the FAQs for more info. Thanks.

Comment: 15$ on Appstore, EasyFind is free :)

Answer (score 0):

Insider 1.1.1 is from 2013 but regardless, appears to work well on macOS 10.15.7 Catalina.  However, as of now (Feb 2023) its purchase-website is dead. I just hope the trial period is infinite...

Its searching is apparently based on Spotlight backed up by find and grep (hence is not constrained to what has been Spotlight-indexed).